# Cronjob with script with sudo commands not running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scripts, sudo, cron, email

I'm trying to get a script with commands that have to be executed as sudo to run daily using cron. I've installed the cron job using

```
sudo crontab -e
```

but it doesn't seem to execute...

It's a script that sends me the output of two command on my Plex server in my email every day. When I run this manually (sudo ~/report.sh it does work) This is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

touch file.tmp /usr/local/lib/PlexConnect/PlexConnect_daemon.bash
status > file.tmp service plexmediaserver status >> file.tmp 
if [ -s    file.tmp ] 
then
       mailx -s "Plex daily report $(date)" 8901190836@donboscokortrijk.be <file.tmp 
fi 
rm file.tmp
```

This is the line for the cronjob:

```
34 15 * * * ~/report.sh
```

When I run the command manually, I receive the email. When I use it in a crontab, nothing... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're installing a **root** cronjob when using `sudo crontab -e`.

`~/report.sh` will expand to `/root/report.sh`

Better to use full paths in your cronjob.